# Error expected primary-expression before '||' token

Tags: c++

Currently trying to complete my C++ Assignment, the code isnt complete yet, but I was just trying to compile it and I ran into this error. I cant seem to figure out how to fix it, any pointers? Please excuse this super noobie question.. im still a beginner in an intro course.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvUUh.png)

Comment: Please post your code. Don't just give us the link of an image.

Comment: Use `if (animal == 'D' || animal == 'd')`

Comment: Your if conditionals are not syntactically correct. You should surround them with ()

Answer (score 2):

Your **parentheses** are messed up. An `if` statement condition in C++ should be wrapped in a parenthesis like so:

```
if ( animal == 'D' || animal == 'd' )...

if ( status == 'Y' || status == 'y' )...

else if ( status == 'N' || status == 'n')...
```

Answer (score 1):

You if condition must be enclosed by a single bracket

```
if ((animal == 'D') || (animal == 'd'))
```

&

```
if((status == 'Y) || (status == 'y))
```

&

```
else if((status == 'N') || (status == 'n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your If syntax is wrong, sweetie. You have missed the round brackets.
Should be:

```
if((status == 'N') || (status == 'n'))
```